# Gradle is not automatically adding jar into project

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

Here is my build.gradle file
when I compile it always says 'cannot find symbol class HtmlFetcher' which is inside the de.jetwick.snacktory dependency

jar file of snacktory library is downloaded into local gradle cache
but it is not including it into project.
what might be a problem?

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.7.+'
    }
}
apply plugin: 'android'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    maven {url "https://github.com/karussell/mvnrepo/raw/master/releases"}
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 18
    buildToolsVersion "18.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 19
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            runProguard false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:+'
    compile 'de.jetwick:snacktory:1.1'
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: '*.jar')
}
```

Comment: Check my answer in this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19063133/android-studio-marks-syntax-as-error-but-gradle-compiles/21263279#21263279

Comment: I guess that would be not correct solution. I already added maven repo and I want gradle automatically add it into my project. If I add it manually why should I use gradle?

Comment: What version of Android Studio are you running?

Comment: Do you make it work? I get a java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Ljava/beans/Introspector; when I initialize fetcher HtmlFetcher fetcher = new HtmlFetcher();

Comment: If I remember correctly, updating android studio fixed the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Upgrade to Android Studio 0.4.3. There are bugs with adding dependencies that have been fixed since 0.4.0.

Answer (score 0):

```
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: '*.jar')
```

That is the same line I use to compile my libs directory. I'm not sure if it's the version, as I've been using the above gradle line since 0.3 or so, and it's worked fine.

The only other thing to check would be the location of your libs folder.

Your libs folder needs to be inside of your Module.

Android studio projects are the same as IntelliJ projects meaning that the directory structure should be: `ProjectName/ModuleName/libs`

That means you need a libs directory on the same level as your src directory and build.gradle file. Double check it's in the right location.

Comment: That's not correct solution when you are using gradle for dependency management. You can use it only when you have a custom or non-maven repo packages. anyway thanks

Comment: Oops, I'm sorry. I misread your question. I thought the problem was coming from something in the libs directory.